# CSS display none removes the element, but leaves its occupied space

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

In my chart, I would like to remove some of the legend items based on a condition and I am using CSS, display none, from JS controller. Removing works fine, however, a blank space is left at the element's occupied space. Why?

As this HTML is generated dynamically, I am presenting a screenshot from the front-end, in which display: none is highlighted. I attempted to edit tags, play with CSS, in the browser, but nothing helped. The blank space remains still.

[image]

And here is the JS controller section that hides the item, but I think the issue is in HTML/CSS. Any help is appreciated.

```
chart: {
    //.....................................

    callback: function (chart) {


         var legendItems = document.getElementsByClassName('nv-series');

         for (var x = 0; x < legendItems.length; x++) {
                                                
             var legendItem = legendItems[x];
             var content = legendItem.textContent.trim();

             if (content.indexOf('Item 3') !== -1 || content.indexOf('Item 7') !== -1) {
                                 
                 legendItem.style.display = 'none';

              }
          }

     }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @HereticMonkey how else should he show is the live HTML?

Comment: It's not the "live HTML"; it's a screenshot of some SVG. If the OP really wants to show the issue, they should show a complete [mre].

Comment: All your elements use `translate`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate therefore even if some have `display: none` the other elements are still translated.

Comment: @roko nice copying

Comment: @HereticMonkey it's NOT just "some" SVG, it's a picture of the inspect element tab. Maybe he's using a framework that's way too complex to put in a snippet

Comment: Nonetheless, it should be trivial to copy the code from the Elements pane to the question. If you right-click an element in Chrome's Elements panel, the Copy menu item expands, and one of the items is Copy outerHTML. There is no reason to use an image to show textual information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blank space is because the other elements are being transformed to be offset by a certain amount, and that amount stays the same even if one element is hidden.

So when you hide one element, either loop through all of the elements that follow it and manually subtract the width of the hidden element from the `translate-x` amount, or make another way of listing the elements side by side without using the `transform` property.